# Ways to import data into AzureSQL PaaS from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: t-sql, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

All,

I have to BULK Insert data into **AzureSQL** from a **Azure Blob Storage** Account. I know one way is to use SAS keys but are there more secure ways to load data from **T-SQL**?

For example, is there a way to use the users **AAD account** to connect to the Storage? Would **Managed Identity** work? I have not come across an example in the Internet that uses anything other than SAS Keys.

Gopi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

azure data factory generally serves this purpose. You can build a pipeline that grabs data from blob and massages it / loads it into sql, kind of what it's designed for.  However if you do not wish to use that,
the recommended way is SAS because it can be temporary and revoked at any time. Why do you think SAS is less secure?

as per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#credential--credential_name if you were to create an external data source with blob_storage type the identity/credentials MUST be SAS, as it doesn't support any other authentication type. as such, that means you cannot use any other auth method to a blob storage using tsql.

Comment: Because it is difficult to restrict based on IP address (for AzureSQL). Since credentials are stored in the database too dont know how it might get misused when the backups are created by Microsoft

Comment: if you feel that's scary, you could create an azure keyvault and integrate it with azure sql tsql script then the SAS won't be "stored" in the database but in the keyvault perhaps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/azure-key-vault-integration-configure